# I don't understand why my for loop return "undefined"

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm trying to create a loop for two arrays at the same time, but the execution return me "undefined" and I don't understand why... Can you please take a look at my code and show me the way ?

```js
var questions = ["a", "b", "c"];
var responses = [5, 45, "test"];

var correctionList = "";
for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++); {

  correctionList += questions[i] + ' : ' + responses[i];

  var newLi = document.createElement('li');
  var liContent = document.createTextNode(correctionList);
  newLi.appendChild(liContent);

  console.log(correctionList);

  var showCorrection = document.querySelector('#correction-list');
  showCorrection.appendChild(newLi);

  console.log(liContent);
}
```

```html
<ol id="correction-list"></ol>
```

I expect a list with "questions : responses"

Comment: You seem to have no return statement?

Comment: There is a `;` after the loop.

Comment: it's a typo, use an editor that can highlight those for you, try webstorm or vscode

Comment: I don't have any return statement. Should I return something inside the loop ?

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed Why would the editor highlight syntactically valid code? You'd need a *linter*.

Comment: Wow... i did not see the ; after the looop... Thanks a lot !!!!!!

Comment: @Bergi maybe because both editors I suggested support linters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last `undefined` you are seeing is probably because of the absence of function return statement. This happens only when you are printing something on your browser console.

Just refactored the code a bit to show the list of questions and answer in the format question:response

```
function createList() {
    var questions = ["a", "b", "c"];
    var responses = [5, 45, "test"];

    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {

       // Changed this line
       var correctionList = questions[i] + ' : ' + responses[i];

       var newLi = document.createElement('li');
       var liContent = document.createTextNode(correctionList);
       newLi.appendChild(liContent);

       var showCorrection = document.querySelector('#correction-list');
       showCorrection.appendChild(newLi);
}

createList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I 'm trying this ! :)